# I can't launch xdebug on mac OS + VS Code + MAMP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, mamp, xdebug

When I put the phpinfo here https://xdebug.org/wizard.
in Summary I got the following info:
PHP Version: 7.3.7
Zend API nr: 320180731
PHP API nr: 20180731
I downloaded xdebug
But when I run phpize it shows me different info - but it should be the same as previously mentioned
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902

Then I go to FAQ and Run: "phpize --help and it shows /usr/local/bin/phpize path
Then I run php-config --version and it shows 7.4.7 - different from which MAMP uses
then follow the solution described next, run

1. /usr/local/bin/phpize
2. ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.7/bin/php-config
   but it didn't help
   Looks like somehow I need to make my phpize show
   PHP Api Version:         20180731
   Zend Module Api No:      20180731
   Zend Extension Api No:   320180731

or make MAMP use 7.4.7 version
But how I do not know
Please advise what should I do to fix this
Thank you in advance!